# Count number of nodes in binary tree with leaves

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-tree

Main class Tree

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, root, size):
        self.root = None
        self.size = 0

    def count_nodes(self):
        if self.value is None:
            return -1
        else:
        return 1 + self.count_nodes(self.left) + self.count_nodes(self.right)

            #self.size += 1
            #if self.left is not None:
                #self.left.count_nodes()
            #if self.right is not None:
                #self.right.count_nodes()
            #return self.size
```

with subclasses Node and Leaf

```
class Node (Tree):
    def __init__(self, value, left, right):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.value = value

class Leaf (Tree):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
```

What do I do when encountered a Leaf? I tried the above 2 methods and still do not know how to handle when leaf is encountered.

Sample tree would be the following and `tree.count-nodes()`should return 7

```
tree = Node ("one",
             Node ("two", Leaf ("three"), Leaf ("four")),
             Node ("five", Leaf ("six"), Leaf ("seven")))
```

Comment: Why do you need a `Leaf` class? A leaf is just a `Node` with `None` children.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct - the number of nodes in a binary tree is equal to *1(the root node)* + *nodes_in_left_subtree(if exists)* + *nodes_in_right_subtree(if exists)*. This is recursive definition and can be implemented as recursive function as you tried.

In your implementation you have some flaws:

- you are not checking if the subtrees actually exist
- `self.left` and `self.right` are actually `Tree` and you should call `call_nodes` on these `Tree`s not on `self`

P.S. Your code in not syntactically correct. The check `self.value is None` is strange for me but it may be true for your problem domain. `root` variable is never used. You can think if you really need it with current data organization.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of having an another subclass to count leaves. You can count all nodes like this:

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, root, size):
        self.root = None
        self.size = 0

    def count_nodes(self,root):
        if (root.right is None and root.left is None) :
            return -1
        else:
        return 1 + self.count_nodes(self.left) + self.count_nodes(self.right)
```